# How do I make multiple retrofit calls in different tabs, tablayout?

Tags: android, retrofit, rx-java

I have stumbled upon similar answers and learnt that RxJava is used for multiple retrofit requests. I have 3 tabs for details of a movies, reviews of a movie and trailers of movie.

In reviews tab, I should make a call to fetch reviews for that movie and in trailers tab I should make a call to fetch trailers. So in this case should I use rxjava to make multiple calls or is it possible with retrofit ?

Comment: you could use `call.enque(new Callback<>{...})` and then deal with the single `onResponse`s

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't have to use Rxjava for that. You could make somthing like this:

```
// Get details

Call<ResponseBody> detailCall = apiInterface.getDetails();
detailCall .enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});

// Get reviews

Call<ResponseBody> reviewCall= apiInterface.getReviews();
reviewCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});

// Get trailers

Call<ResponseBody> trailerCall= apiInterface.getTrailer();
trailerCall.enqueue(new Callback<ResponseBody>() {
    @Override
    public void onResponse(Call<ResponseBody> call, Response<ResponseBody> response) {

    }

    @Override
    public void onFailure(Call<ResponseBody> call, Throwable t) {

    }
});
```

Comment: How is it possible to have same variable name 'call' for 3 calls ?

Answer (score 0):

Well, each of your tab show different aspect of the same movie. Consider using MVP pattern, in which model is responsible for all REST calls, and contain different details of that movie, and TabLayout having fragments. Every fragment implement 'view' from MVP - pattern. Attach all views to the same model and presenter during ViewPager initialization (see https://github.com/google/iosched sample project from Google, for example, class MyScheduleActivity: https://github.com/google/iosched/blob/master/android/src/main/java/com/google/samples/apps/iosched/myschedule/MyScheduleActivity.java )